# Calculate if a line will pass through a given point?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, fixed-points

I'm not sure if this should be in math or physics so I'm asking in both.

Given a laser beam in closed reflective surface where point $(x,y)$ is the source of a laser beam which hits a reflective surface at $(x_1,y_1)$, how can I(if possible) tell if the beam will hit point $(x_2,y_2)$ at some point??

where the values of $x,y,x_1,y_1$ are given.

**note:** The beam could $(x_2,y_2)$ after multiple reflections.

[image: reflective Box]

Comment: Use modular arithmetic.  if there were no walls the equation for the particle of light would be $y=mx + b$.  If the the room is $h$ and width is $w$ if there is a solution to $(\pm y + kh)=m(\pm x + jw)$ then that point will hit.  Note that whether to use $\pm y, \pm x$ will depend if $k,j$ are even or odd.

Comment: The drawing shows a box, but the question asks about a "closed reflective surface" (presumably in 2D, given the coordinates...), so the modular-arithmetic idea isn't strong enough to answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. I *think* that this is generally an open question, even for convex boundaries in 2D.
2. There are some cases where you have to be quite careful to define exactly what you mean. For instance, consider a deep V-shaped groove, with a laser shining into it from above. The laser bounces back and forth from wall to wall, and (if you set up the angles right), all odd-numbered segments of the path are parallel; all even-numbered segments are parallel. The "bounce points" approach the vertex of the V-shape. In this case, do you say that they reach the vertex, or not? It might take infinitely many bounces to do so, and when the path **does** "reach" the vertex, there's no well-defined "previous bounce".

Comment: so does my question have a solution?

Comment: See part 1 of my answer: for a general convex boundary, I believe that there's no known way to tell without simply computing all possible reflections (which may take infinitely long) to see whether the target point lies on any of them. For certain special cases, the question may be easy (e.g., region is a rectangle; initial ray is parallel to one side of the box). For more general cases, it **may** be easy to show that the ray comes *arbitrarily close* to your target point (e.g., $1 \times \sqrt{2}$ axis-aligned box, initial ray of slope 1, comes arbitrarily close to every point of the box).

Comment: i see , the only thing i have is the surface is a closed 3D surface , with reflective surface horizontally parallel to the source

Comment: "Horizontally parallel to the source" is too vague to mean anything to me, but the key point is that it's not necessarily a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The light ray can hit every point of present in the reflecting room.

Ponder over this construction :

[image]

---

Edit 1 - A possible construction for a specific case

[image]

---

Edit 2 - Multiple Reflections

Let there be 2 reflections from different surfaces. Then the following construction gives us the path of the light ray.

Let the last reflection be from the bottom surface:

[image]

And let the first reflection be from the left surface:

[image]

Now, draw the rays

[image]

Comment: What if the light ray hits an edge traveling perpendicular to that edge then it cannot visit every point? I think the OP is asking (at least how I interpreted the question) if given a starting point and a direction can you determine if the light ray will eventually pass through another given point?

Comment: so what if it reaches point F after multiple reflection?? how can i find out that it did?

Comment: @AkashJain See my edit... You just need to to do that reflection trick about your desired reflecting surface the number of times you wish the light ray to reflect. I have shown it for 2 reflections. You may try it for more.

Comment: What if the surface is not rectangular? The original question asks about general surfaces; the rectangle is just an illustrative example. (Or maybe OP didn't intend to ask in full generality, but hasn't bothered to say so. Sigh.)

Comment: @JohnHughes I have only considered the case as mentioned in the diagram of the question. Also I only present graphical and intuitive proofs on MSE. So if the question had mentioned exclusively about a general surface, which would definitely involve rigorous mathematical functions, I wouldn't have bothered to answer the question.

Comment: thank you this has given a new perspective but just curious wouldn't the same logic apply for any given surface??

Comment: @AkashJain If you can effectively reflect every point of the interior w.r.t every point on the peripheri of the surface, this logic would work. But that is a kind of surface to surface mapping which becomes more complex for curved surfaces